# Installing and using dcfldd on 20.04.4 LTS

Tags: 20.04, make, tar, dd, secure-erase

I was unable to install dcfldd onto my live-ubuntu-usb which I want to do in order to wipe my HD that I am planning to sell.
I tried both with simple

```
sudo apt install dcfldd
```

As well as by trying to manually install the tar.gz or tar.xz files.
However, neither method seems to work as it can't locate the dcfldd pkg automatically and there doesn't seem to be an install.sh file only an INSTALL readme as well as an install-sh file.
Not sure if I am supposed to rename it from install-sh to install.sh or what because the readme as well as the INSTALL readme doesn't actually let you know how to actually install.
I was able to install make as well as use the ./config commands but I tried chmod +x as well as sudo ./install-sh and various variations without success.  I even tried to use the debian.tar.xz as well as teh tar.gz files without success.

I wanted to thank @steeldriver, @NOrbert and others for their answer and help.
Although I do enable the universe repository for my actual desktop, I didn't realize that it was not enabled on the "Try Ubuntu" live-usb by default.
So as their link states, run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install dcfldd
```

Then in order to wipe the main harddrive with my live usb I used:

```
sudo dcfldd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda statusinterval=10 bs=10M conv=notrunc
```

This gives progress on the writing of zeroes through the main drive.  Using "urandom" instead of "zero", may work to write random numbers through the drive which some believe to be more effective.
Wipe command was taking too long and during the wait I discovered that some considered dcfldd more secure.

Comment: For the apt method, did you enable the `universe` repository first?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) as per  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=dcfldd .